# Should I add the award of a Graduate Research Fellowship to my CV before I start it?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, cv

I have been awarded a Graduate Research Fellowship from the grad school I intend to attend. It will start in Fall 2023. Should I add it to my CV in advance?

If yes, how should I mention it there? If no, why do you think that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you add it, list it with dates so that it is clear to readers. You can say "... beginning Sept. 2023", or "forthcoming" or similar.

The only real issue is being clear.

But, I wonder why you need to do this if you've already accepted a position. Your CV isn't going to be used much, I'd guess, in the short term.

Comment: There is no specific need of this in my CV in this short period of time, Professor. It's just, I update my CV pretty frequently. I try to keep it as updated as possible.